# Clarification of definition of lim sup of a set.

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

[image]

Could someone clarify the definiton of the function given above?
I think it means $\omega_f(a)=\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=m}^{\infty}\{ |f(x')-f(x'')| : a-\frac{1}{n} < x',x''< a+\frac{1}{n} \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the correct interpretation is

$$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\big(\sup\{ |f(x')-f(x'')| : a-\frac{1}{n} < x',x''< a+\frac{1}{n} \}\big)$$

Comment: Hello, can your definition be reduced to $\inf\{{\sup\{ |f(x')-f(x'')| : a-\frac{1}{n} < x',x''< a+\frac{1}{n} }\}:n\leq 0\}$?

Comment: No, I don't think so. That would only be the case if the function were continuous.